# Password protected zip archives open without password

Tags: kali-linux, password, zip

I have a zip archive that is password protected in linux(the password is "secret"). However, whenever I try to open the zip file I am not prompted for a password or anything. I also have a python script that extracts zip archives and purposely passes an incorrect password and it still unzips the archive anyway. I am not running as root either as I heard root likes to ignore file permissions. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

I zipped my folder "evil" into a zip file "evil.zip" and gave it a password by using the command:

```
zip --pasword secret -r evil.zip evil
```

The python script unzip.py reads:

```
import zipfile
zFile = zipfile.ZipFile("evil.zip")
zFile.extractall(pwd="oranges")
```

I am running Kali Linux 1.0.9 and Zip (v. 3.0)

I also tried to use the encrypt command instead of password:

```
zip --encrypt -r evil.zip evil
```

That prompted me for a password at which I set it to secret.

I ended up with the message:

```
Traceback (mostrecent call last) :
 File "unzip.py", line 3, in <module>
  zFile.extractall(pwd="oranges")
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unzip.py", line 980, in extractall
  self.extract(zipinfo, path, pwd)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unzip.py", line 968, in extract
  return self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unzip.py", line 1011, in _extract_member
  source = self.open(member, pwd=pwd)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unzip.py", line 952, in open
  raise RuntimeError("Bad password for file", name)
RuntimeError: ('Bad password for file', <zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x23a0118>)
```

And then the folder still unzips.

Comment: May be you need to use `-e` flag to enable encryption: `zip --pasword secret -er evil.zip evil`

Comment: It doesn't work for me: `RuntimeError: ('Bad password for file', <zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0xb71f926c>)`

Comment: Well, as I said some hours ago, this is specific to your distro/software version. It works absolutely fine for me with `zip --encrypt -r evil.zip evil`. If I try to unpack it with `unzip`, it's asking for password. If I try the same with `python` (3) it works fine with the right password and I get the same message as Arkadiusz if I give a wrong password, e.g. `zFile.extractall(pwd=b"oranges")` (it does create an empty directory `evil` but that's all).

Answer (score 3):

It's the files in the archive that are encrypted and password protected, not the directory structure.  This means that you will be able to extract the *directories* from the archive even though it's encrypted (but not the files).

To encrypt the archive in a way so that this is not possible, I'd suggest using something like GnuPG instead.

Answer (score -4):

At a guess, it's because you're running Kali. That distro was designed to 'get around' security features (with the legitimate purpose of highlighting flaws in security). I don't think you'd encounter this 'error' in any other distro.

Comment: "Get around security features" by shipping a broken `zip` utility?

Comment: This answer is completely incorrect. You can't simply bypass zip encryption via a modified zip binary (if you could, the encryption would be worthless).